# Is there a way to check if text string is valid HTML in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am writing a simple CMS in Rails 4. And I am storing my articles in database as text strings that contains HTML code (not necessary).

Anyway, I need a method to check before saving, if the text of the article is valid HTML or nor (considering that the article is not full HTML document, but the part of it, without DOCTYPE and other stuff). Something like this: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options ("Validate HTML fragment"), but working inside my Rails application as validation method of the model, so if my markup is wrong, it should not save the article and show the error message instead.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using markdown for the content... if that suits your needs (basic markup, images, etc). It's pretty straightforward to implement and there are some nice lightweight javascript libraries that provide the interface. This way you don't need to bother about valid HTML.

Comment: (this website is using it as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to achieve this using `w3c_validators` gem.

1. Add `gem 'w3c_validators'` to Gemfile and run `bundle install`.
2. Change model. I've added a custom validation method to validate HTML, like this:

   ```
   class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
       validate :valid_html

       def valid_html
         @validator = MarkupValidator.new

         html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>title</title></head><body>#{text}</body></html>"

         results = @validator.validate_text(html)

         if results.errors.length > 0
           results.errors.each do |err|
             errors.add(:text, err.to_s)
           end
         end
       end
     end
   ```

(I need to wrap my code into HTML and BODY tags and add some more tags, because I don't store full HTML in my DB, only partials).

Comment: `w3c_validators` gem hits the w3c external service. Is there a way to do this locally/without relying on a service?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to check input for a field in rails you can simply utilize 3 things which are

1. Rails [before_save](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback
2. JS/Ajax for checking input (avoid page reloading)
3. Constraints in which you define to be valid HTML

In your model you could create a method in which checks to see if the text inserted into the field is valid. Before the form is saved it would check to see if the inserted HTML meets your definition of valid HTML.